# Extending JavaScript String and JQuery.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Last two days I'm trying to understand one problem with my code.

Code is here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/a7wkpngr/

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
};



$.ajax({
    url: '/',
    data: $.extend({}, "")
})
```

If you'll try to run this code you can see

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function // of course, coz this === window
```

I was trying to find "WHY". I found, that:

1. Problem is in `$.extend` (if second argument is object there are no exceptions).
2. If you'll run `$.extend` without `$.ajax`, everything is ok

   There is NOTHING about capitalize in Jquery source.

So, the question is - how and why `String.capitalize()` runs.

P.S. I know, I know, it's very bad to extend native Classes.

Comment: You're using `$.extend()` in right way. This function accepts both arguments as key value objects.

Comment: The `capitalize` method is called because `$.extend({}, "")` returns an object which has a property called `capitalize()`... the ajax method will invoke the functions which are passed as part of an `data` key.. in this case the value of `capitalize` is an function so that is invoked by the ajax framework - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bcq5ktun/2/

Comment: now the question is why is the `capitalize` property copied to `data` where as other `prototype` properties of `String` is not copied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By debugging the code, you can see that, while using extend with empty option, it will go to this line 201 in jquery source code (version 2.0.1).

if you put breakpoint here, when ajax extend is called. Length of parameter is 2. one is  {} and other "".

```
for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
    // Only deal with non-null/undefined values
    if ( (options = arguments[ i ]) != null ) {
        // Extend the base object
        for ( name in options ) {
            src = target[ name ];
            copy = options[ name ];
```

loop on property here for ( name in options ), iterates over properties of String, so actually it should add all string properties but it's only adding capitalize function you have added and returning that to ajax parameters. first for loop only executes once because if length 2 and inner for runs only once i.e. on capitalize method.

Now check the output of following:

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
};

String.prototype.capitalize2 = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
};
String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
};
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'test',
{
    value: function(){ return "test" },
    enumerable: false
});

Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'test2',
{
    value: function(){ return "test" },
    enumerable: true
});

for (var key in "") {

console.log(key);
}
```

Output in console:

**capitalize** 
**capitalize2**
**test2**

Which leads to say you for in iterating only through the properties which are enumerable.

Check jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/w9kdp96a/1/

and from mozilla:

> The for..in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an
>   object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can
>   be executed.

So if you define the the capitalize method as

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'capitalize',
{
    value: function(){ return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1); },
    enumerable: false
});
```

It will not in ajax data.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

1. `toUpperCase()` is JavaScript.  For instance, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp).
2. You can see your prototype function working with `console.log('hello'.capitalize());`
3. The purpose of $.extend is to merge to objects, so your second argument is broken:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        data: $.extend({}, {"hello":"world"})
    })
```

will result in `data: {"hello","world"}` as part of your `$.ajax()` call.

The error was caused by the 2nd argument to $.extend() being a string, not an object.

Comment: I know that second argument should be an object, the only question is how and why `String.capitalize` runs, I just can't find where it runs in jquery source.

Comment: To run String.capitalize you'll have to call it... something like
$.extend({},{"hello".capitalize(),"world".capitalize()} would give {"Hello":"World"}.  Prototype adds the function to string's capabilities, but it doesn't automatically apply it to every string.  (Plus, it's plain javascript, not jQuery--you're using jQuery as a library in JavaScript.)

Comment: jquery will call it because it's passed as data to the ajax function. The data will take every illiterateble member and if the member is a function it'll call it (as capitalize is). Yet another reason to leave core objects alone. You don't own these objects so you're breaking encapsulation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice.3A_Extension_of_native_prototypes

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in comments:  `only question is how and why String.capitalize runs,`

if you see the jquery [source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js) it'll take each key of data (foreach(thing in data)) and try to create a query string with that.

If it's a function it'll call it (the comment is from the jquery source code):

```
var prefix,
    s = [],
    add = function( key, value ) {
        // If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
        value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" : value );
        s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( value );
    };
```

SSA's answer could be a solution but Object.defineProperty only works in [IE9 and up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Browser_compatibility).